# AWK - Stripping Out lines of DDL

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following file:

```
CREATE TABLE "DB2INST1 "."EMAIL_ADDRESS"  (
                  "EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                  "PERSON_ID" INTEGER ,
                  "EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
                  "CC_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) ,
                  "UPPER_EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER(EMAIL_ADDRESS)) ,
                 IN "USERSPACE5" INDEX IN "IDXSPACE5" LONG IN "LONGSPCE1" ;


CREATE TABLE "DB2INST "."FIELD_RESPONSE"  (
                  "FIELD_RESPONSE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                  "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID" INTEGER ,
                  "NAME" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
                  "RESPONSE" VARCHAR(100) ,
                  "RESPONSE_LONG" CLOB(256000) LOGGED NOT COMPACT ,
                  "FIELD_RESPONSE_100" VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (case when RESPONSE is null or RESPONSE = '' then cast(RESPONSE_LONG as varchar(100)) else RESPONSE end) ,
                 COMPRESS YES
                 DATA CAPTURE CHANGES
                 IN "USERSPACE1" INDEX IN "IDXSPACE1" LONG IN "LONGSPCE1" ;
```

I am able to strip out each of the these records out of the DDL using the following AWK command:

```
awk '/^CREATE TABLE/ {print}' FS="\n" RS="" < src.ddl > tables.ddl
```

Now, I am trying to remove the GENERATED ALWAYS and everything after that.  I would like the file to look like this (END RESULT):

```
CREATE TABLE "DB2INST1 "."EMAIL_ADDRESS"  (
                  "EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                  "PERSON_ID" INTEGER ,
                  "EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
                  "CC_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) ,
                  "UPPER_EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128)  ,
                 IN "USERSPACE5" INDEX IN "IDXSPACE5" LONG IN "LONGSPCE1" ;


CREATE TABLE "DB2INST "."FIELD_RESPONSE"  (
                  "FIELD_RESPONSE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                  "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID" INTEGER ,
                  "NAME" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
                  "RESPONSE" VARCHAR(100) ,
                  "RESPONSE_LONG" CLOB(256000) LOGGED NOT COMPACT ,
                  "FIELD_RESPONSE_100" VARCHAR(100)  ,
                 COMPRESS YES
                 DATA CAPTURE CHANGES
                 IN "USERSPACE1" INDEX IN "IDXSPACE1" LONG IN "LONGSPCE1" ;
```

I have tried to use this AWK in the

```
|awk '{print $1 "  " $2 ", " }' < tables.ddl ...
```

However, that only prints out two columns of data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can be a good tool for this:

```
sed 's/GENERATED ALWAYS AS.*$/,/' file
```

This gets everything from `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` up to the end of line and replaces it with a comma.

In case you want to do in-place editing, use `-i` as this. It will create a `file.bak` with the current content and `file` will contain the new version.

```
sed -i.bak 's/GENERATED ALWAYS AS.*$/,/' file
```

Comment: This solution is really close.  However, it is not keeping the column name, datatype and the comma.

Comment: What do you mean? It gets `"UPPER_EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER(EMAIL_ADDRESS)) ,` and returns `"UPPER_EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128)  ,`, as you asked in the question... I think this is the requirement, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to your code: uses [gensub](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions)...

```
awk '/^CREATE TABLE/ {print gensub(/GENERATED ALWAYS .*\n/,",\n","g") "\n";}' FS="\n" RS="" src.ddl > tables.ddl
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working on my master file.  I will post the bigger file in a couple of hours ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""}/^CREATE TABLE/{sub(/GENERATED ALWAYS.*,/, ","); print}' src.ddl > tables.ddl
```

Excpected output:

```
CREATE TABLE "DB2INST1 "."EMAIL_ADDRESS"  (
                  "EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                  "PERSON_ID" INTEGER ,
                  "EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
                  "CC_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) ,
                  "UPPER_EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR(128) ,
                 IN "USERSPACE5" INDEX IN "IDXSPACE5" LONG IN "LONGSPCE1" ;
CREATE TABLE "DB2INST "."FIELD_RESPONSE"  (
                  "FIELD_RESPONSE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                  "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID" INTEGER ,
                  "NAME" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
                  "RESPONSE" VARCHAR(100) ,
                  "RESPONSE_LONG" CLOB(256000) LOGGED NOT COMPACT ,
                  "FIELD_RESPONSE_100" VARCHAR(100) ,
                 COMPRESS YES
                 DATA CAPTURE CHANGES
                 IN "USERSPACE1" INDEX IN "IDXSPACE1" LONG IN "LONGSPCE1" ;
```

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah noticed it earlier but forgot in my last edit. Somehow I also just didn't want to touch it but ok I'll edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working on my master file.  I will post the bigger file in a couple of hours ...